# How to schedule a class to send emails with user's email as sender?

Tags: email-template, scheduled-apex

Right now every email my scheduled class sends has my email in the replyTo address field, even though in the template I set up so it would get the record's user email, like in:

```
replyTo="{!relatedTo.CreatedBy.Email}"
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all. And I need this to be set for the specific object, so I can't use a org-wide email default address.

I have tried removing the `replyTo` line from the template, and setting it on the class code with `email.setReplyTo('email@example.com')`, but this doesn't work either.

I'm using the following code inside my class:

```
Messaging.reserveMassEmailCapacity(1);
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage sem = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

sem.setBccAddresses(new String[]{q.CreatedBy.Email, q.Contact.Email});
sem.saveAsActivity = false;
sem.setTargetObjectId(q.Contact.Id);
sem.setReplyTo(q.CreatedBy.Email);
sem.setWhatId(q.Id);
emails.add(sem);
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
```

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: I think since you are the one who setup the schedule, it always pickups your email address. I don't think you can change this behavior.

Comment: @kvnfv I've updated my question with the code I'm using.

Comment: @SLman is there any place where this behavior is specified?